# duplicate HL7 code in Mirth property file mapping

Tags: file, properties, mirth

Incoming HL7 messages may have the same code for multiple fields

Ex:  The code 'S' in marital status is map to '1' and the code 'S' in financial class is map to 'g'.

The problem occurs when loaded in Mirth, since the code is same in marital status and financial class the marital status code 'S' value is overwritten by the value (our product code) of financial class code 'S'.

Here is the sample mappings which you can find in 'hl7_mapping.properties' file regarding above problem. Please note 'S'

> Marital status Mapping
>  
>   left side HL7 Value : right side product Value

```
S=1 
M=2
```

> Financial Class
>  
>   left side HL7 Value : right side product Value

```
D=d
S=g
FED=f
```

much obliged anyone can provide solutions which you think is best to load multiple values(product code) for the same code without overwriting.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying that post-transformation your Marital Status and Financial Class end up having the same value?

Comment: The "hl7_mapping.properties" is not a part of Mirth installation. So the problem occur with your own property file which, hopefully, you can edit and change some values from "S" to "MS" and "FS" for example.

Comment: @LeeCambl  yes,first, 1 will be assigned to S and then  S value will be overridden by the value g  as mirth go through the property file top to bottom, can you suggest any solution to avoid this?

Comment: @user3005941 Thanks for the reply. yes i tried that. but the problem is since i have started my project long time ago. so if i try to map like that i have to do so many changes in code. can you please suggest another solution or is there any way i can provide a global solution for this problem?

Comment: Without seeing what your channel(s) is doing it's hard to guess the best solution. The easiest thing that came to my mind is to after reading the property file replace the marital status mapping back as needed.

Comment: @user3005941 Thanks again. can you please describe how to do that?